# Why do I have to import certain things like datetime, etc from the standard library but don't have to import print(), len(), etc...?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why can't these just be included when I'm writing a program? I feel that certain `standard library` functions like `datetime` are used so often, that it becomes a pain to keep on `importing` it whenever it is need.

Comment: Because most code needs to have the built-ins, while the remainder can be grouped in libraries. It's a balancing act; not clutter the namespace for things that are not always needed and easy access to those things you almost always need.

Comment: One can argue that `datetime` are not as important as `print`, `len` or `map` though, so it deserves its own module

Comment: Why don't they add a butterfly net on a Swiss army knife?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque What kind of low-end Swiss army knife do *you* have? :)

Comment: A proper IDE will also ease your import pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You* think that `datetime` is used often enough to warrant it being built-in to the language. *I*, however, hardly ever use it in the code I write.

What to include as a built-in is somewhat subjective, and the decision can change over time. Some examples:

- The `print` statement was "demoted" to a built-in function in Python 3.
- The `reduce` function was demoted from a built-in function to a library function (in the `functools` module) in Python 3.
- The `apply` function was removed as a built-in function in Python 2; to my knowledge, it was not added to the standard library at all in Python 3.
- Certain functions in the `itertools`  module were effectively promoted to built-in status in Python 3; e.g., the built-in `map` is no longer a function, but a class whose instances are similar to the return value of `itertools.imap`.
- Matrix multiplication was previously only supplied by custom library routines; in Python 3.5, a special operator `@` with a corresponding magic method `__matmul__` was added to the language. (The *implementation* still needs to be added on a class-by-class basis, but the framework is built into the language.)